# Running for loop across multiple groups

Tags: r, for-loop, split, lapply

I am running the following imputation task in R as a for loop:

```
myData <- essuk[c(2,3,4,5,6,12)]
myDataImp <- matrix(0,dim(myData)[1],dim(myData)[2])

lower <- c(0)
upper <- c(Inf)

for (k in c(1:5))
{
  gmm.fit1 <- gmm.tmvnorm(matrix(myData[,k],length(myData[,k]),1), lower=lower, upper=upper)

  useMu <- matrix(gmm.fit1$coefficients[1],1,1)
  useSigma <- matrix(gmm.fit1$coefficients[2],1,1)
  replaceThese <- myData[,k]<=0
  myDataImp[,k] <- myData[,k]

  myDataImp[replaceThese,k]  <- rtmvnorm(n=sum(replaceThese), c(useMu), c(useSigma), c(-Inf), c(0))
}
```

The steps are pretty straightforward

- Define the data set and an empty imputation data set.
- For column 1-5, fit a model.
- Extract model estimates to be used for imputation.
- Run a model using model estimates and replace values <= 0 with the new values in the imputation data set.

However, I want to do this separately for multiple groups, rather than for the full sample. Column 12 in the data set contains information on group membership (integers ranging from 1-72).

I have tried several options, including splitting the data frame with `data_list <- split(myData, myData$V12)` and use the `lapply()` function. However, this does not work due to how model estimates are formatted:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ""gmm"" to a data.frame
```

I have also thought about the possibility of doing a nested for loop, although I am not sure how that could be accomplished. Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Pls provide reproducible example of essuk or myData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using subset() ?

```
myData$V12 = as.factor(myData$V12)
listofresults= c()
for (i in levels(myData$V12)){
data = subset (myData, myData$V12 == i)
  #your analysis here: result saved in myDataImp

 listofresults = c(listofresults, myDataImp)
}
```

not the most elegant, but should work.

Comment: That worked like a charm! I guess there should be a way around it using the apply() framework rather than a double loop, but your suggestion is doing the job as well. Also, while my data set is not particularly large, double loops could potentially cause issues for larger data sets or more complicated models.